# how to run seperate files in fastapi platform?

Tags: python, module, fastapi

I learn now the platform and very happy from it.
but I have a problem when I want to open the python shell or the terminal and run separate files.

It don't accept my imports.

for example, I want to run a file `db.py` inside the "`utils`" directory. both in the main app directory and in utils directory there is "`init.py`" file.
but when I run the file from the terminal with:

```
python db.py
```

it doesn't accept the line :

```
from utils.const import DB_HOST,DB_NAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_USER
```

and i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fastapi-course-1/utils/db.py", line 3, in <module>
from utils.const import DB_HOST,DB_NAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_USER
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

maybe the problem is to define the root directory .... how could i do it ???

thank's !!!

[image: my app tree]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the environment variable PYTHONPATH:

```
 $ export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/main/app/module"
```

Comment: can you explain more on that , my team was assigned to work on individual file and for FastAPI framework it was hard to test